# NoClassDefFoundError:ContainerLifeCycle

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dropwizard

when trying to start my jar file I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/ContainerLifeCycle
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at io.dropwizard.jackson.DiscoverableSubtypeResolver.discoverServices(DiscoverableSubtypeResolver.java:61)
    at io.dropwizard.jackson.DiscoverableSubtypeResolver.<init>(DiscoverableSubtypeResolver.java:34)
    at io.dropwizard.jackson.DiscoverableSubtypeResolver.<init>(DiscoverableSubtypeResolver.java:28)
    at io.dropwizard.jackson.Jackson.newObjectMapper(Jackson.java:27)
    at io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap.<init>(Bootstrap.java:57)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:67)
    at de.com.eusmsserver.EUSMSServerApplication.main(EUSMSServerApplication.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you using any external jar file in your project?

Comment: make sure you have added jar files to the build path

Comment: I am using maven with dropwizard 0.7.0. I have seen that in the Bootstrap.java file within package io.dropwizard.setup, my IDE does not find one of the import files:import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;